# Knockout Observable Array Unexpected Sorting

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, knockout.js, data-binding

Background:
I am currently working on a UI that is using Knockout.  I have been using knockout for a little while but this issue has stumped me.  I am trying to sort an observable array called Actions and bind it to a foreach inside a template I created.  I am binding by creating a computed that is calling the sort function on the Actions array.

Code:

```
self.Actions = ko.observableArray([]);

self.SortedActions = ko.computed(function() {
return self.Actions()
    .sort(function (a, b) {
        var aOrder = Number(a.Order());
        var bOrder = Number(b.Order());

        return aOrder < bOrder ? 1 : -1;
    });
});

<div class="row" data-bind="template: { name: 'action-template', foreach: SortedActions }"></div>
```

Expected Result:
I am trying to get the array to sort off of the Order observable inside each action from 1-n.  I already know that no orders are repeated so that isn't a concern and I know everything will be a whole number starting at 1 and ending at n.

Actual Result:
Everything appears to be working when Actions is < 10 actions long.  However, once it is > 10 the orders are not appearing as I would expect.  They are appearing in the same order every time I load them in, however that order is incorrect and seemingly random.  (meaning it doesn't appear to be sorting of a noticeable pattern. ex. Alphabetically)

If anyone has any ideas as to why this isn't working I would be very grateful.  I have never seen the sort act so odd before and am completely stumped.  Please let me know if you need anymore details.  This is my first post so I probably messed something up.

Thanks,
:)

Comment: A couple of things: `sort` acts on the original array and will therefore also result in `self.Actions` being sorted. You should use `return bOrder - aOrder;` to get the correct result.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve an array that is always in a sorted state?

Comment: Yes, I am wanting an array that will always be sorted for displaying.  This way when I reorder the actions all i need to do is change the order numbers.

Comment: @MichaelBest This isn't working for me either.  This currently gives me and order of [ 8, 1, 7, 14, 12, 11, 10, 9, 2, 13, 6, 5, 4, 3, 15, 16]

Comment: switching my 1 and -1 seems to be fixing the issue.  I would also like to note this list is a little recursive so there were a few changes that were actually need, but everything is currently working as intended with the sorting set as aOrder < bOrder ? -1 : 1;

Comment: If you don't want `Actions` to be sorted every time `SortedActions` is updated, you need to make a copy of the array: `return self.Actions.slice(0).sort...`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subscribe to sort the initial array when the observable changes like so.

Be aware this will sort for every change, as such if you batch up a load of adds directly to the observable it's going to be quite wasteful. You should add to the underlying array and then call `valueHasMutated()`.

If you end up doing this though you may as well just call sort on the array when you need it which would be much clearer.

```js
var viewModel = function(){
  var self = this;
  self.Actions = ko.observableArray(["one", "two", "three"]);

  self.Actions.subscribe(function() {
    console.log("sorting ...");
    self.Actions().sort();
  });
  
  // trigger sorting
  self.Actions.push("zero");
  
  self.addnew = function(){
    self.Actions.push("new" + self.Actions().length);
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ol data-bind="foreach: Actions">
  <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ol>

<button data-bind="click: addnew">Add new</button>
```